# Should sub-objects be fetched in the Model or the Model Mapper?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

This is a follow-up to my previous question: [Should dependent rows be fetched in the Model or the Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163874/should-dependent-rows-be-fetched-in-the-model-or-the-controller).

Let's say that a Patron can check out Books. If, given a Patron object, where and how should the Books they have checked out be fetched?

Here are some possibilities I've considered:

- In the Patron Model, add a `getBooks` method
- When a Patron is instantiated, automatically get its books and store it as the `books` property
- Create a method in the PatronMapper called `getBooks` that takes a Patron ID

What would you recommend? Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to go with:

```
When a Patron is instantiated, automatically get its books and store it as the books property
```

This way you don't have to manually worry about it

Comment: I've always thought that that was the right way to do it, but: Let's say I have a page that lists all the Patron objects in my database. This page doesn't care about what Books the Patron has checked out. Instantiating each Patron object in this case would also make a ton of database requests that aren't needed to display the page. This is the part that I'm torn about.

Comment: that is simple, just make teh constructor accept a bool param. When you do `new Patron(false);` it will not load it's books. Default `new Patron();` will

Comment: I have a follow-up question (another one :) ) if you are interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237991/how-should-changes-to-mvc-objects-be-propagated. Again, I appreciate your help