# How should changes to MVC objects be propagated?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

This is a follow-up to a previous question: [Should sub-objects be fetched in the Model or the Model Mapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237817/should-sub-objects-be-fetched-in-the-model-or-the-model-mapper)

Let's say a User can have one or more PhoneNumber objects. According to the answer in the above question, these sub-objects will be fetched upon instantiation of the User. If I were to delete a PhoneNumber from the User's `phoneNumbers` property (an array of PhoneNumbers), or modify one of the PhoneNumber objects, where should this change be propagated?

Should I manually delete/update the sub-objects in the database, or should the User do that automatically on save? Thank you,

Comment: PhoneNumber ojects doesn't seem the way to go considering PhoneNumber it's max a simple "string". Imo.

Comment: I agree. It's just an example (a stupid example, I realize). Instead of PhoneNumber, it could be any object dependent on a User. This isn't at all my application, by the way; just basic examples.

Comment: ok anyway i tried to add an answer based on my exepiernce, but it's pretty hard to understand this thing with so little particular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see If I got it the right way.

The user is logged and it's on his profile page. On this page the user clicks a link "delete this phone number".

On the page where the action is performed it will executed `DELETE FROM phones ETC`.

Now after this is performed when you will load the User, the constructor will load the phonenumber etc and considering you performed the DELETE sql early the current user object will not have, of course, the just deleted phonenumber.

This is at least what happens in my MVC framework.

Comment: Ok, but, how should it perform an update? I load the User object, it grabs its PhoneNumbers. I change a number. Should I call update on the specific PhoneNumber, or the User itself which will then update its PhoneNumbers?

Comment: @Simple:  the User itself which will then update its PhoneNumbers.

Comment: But I would point another way. You shouldn't load all the User object before you perform the phonenumber etc operation. You should before made the phonenumber update then load the User Object.. at this point you will have synched data